# ¿Mi programa de pila es correcto?

Tags: c, pilas, stack

Hice este programa de una pila, pero aveces en el arreglo de "salida" me saca datos que no son, es decir, le doy a retirar y aveces me pasa el dato retirado a el arreglo "salida" como debe de ser, pero otras veces me pone numeros muy grandes (que supongo que son las localidades de memoria) y despues el numero retirado. 
Se que para hacer un programa de una pila o cola o cualquier estructura de datos lineal debo usar estructuras(struct), pero soy algo novato en esto de c. Aqui el codigo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void agregar();
void retirar();
void imprimirpila();
void imprimirsalida();
int *maxi, *mini, pila[5], *t, tam=0, *salida=(int*)calloc(tam,sizeof(int));
main(void){
    int opc=0;
    mini=&pila[0];
    maxi=&pila[4];
    t=NULL;
    printf("\t\tPila\n");
    do{
       printf("\n¿que desea?\n");
       inicio:
       printf("1.-agregar\n");
       printf("2.-Retirar\n");
       printf("3.-Salir\n");
       scanf("%d",&opc);
       switch(opc){
            case 1:
                agregar();
                break;
            case 2:
                tam++;
                salida=(int*)realloc(salida, tam*sizeof(int));
                retirar();
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nOPCION NO VALICA\n");
                system("pause");
                goto inicio;
       }
    }while(opc<3);
    system("pause");
    free(salida);
    return 0;
}

void agregar(void){
    int dato;
    if(t==maxi){
        printf("\nPILA LLENA\n");
        system("pause");
    }else{
        printf("\nDame un numero para agregar: ");
        scanf("%d", &dato);
        if(t==NULL){
            t=mini;
            printf("mini= %d; t=%d, *t=%d",mini,t, *t);
            t[0]=dato;
            imprimirpila();
        }else{
            t++;
            printf("\n*t=%d; t=%d",*t, t);
            t[0]=dato;
            imprimirpila();
        }
    }
}

void retirar(void){
    if(t==NULL){
        printf("\nPILA VACIA\n");
    }else{
        if(t==mini){
            salida[tam-1]=t[0];
            t[0]=0;
            imprimirpila();
            imprimirsalida();
            t=NULL;
        }else{
            salida[tam-1]=t[0];
            t[0]=0;
            t--;
            imprimirpila();
            imprimirsalida();
        }
    }
}
void imprimirpila(void){
    int i=0;
    printf("\nPila: \n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d  ",pila[i]);
    }
}

void imprimirsalida(void){
    int i=0;
    printf("\nSalida: \n");
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        printf("%d  ",salida[i]);
    }
}
```

Agradeceria si alguien me puede ayudar o si tienen algun comentario de mi codigo.

Answer (score 0):

**Recomendacion**

Una pila se puede ver mejor como una lista en la cual puedes consultar y eliminar el primer elemento, preguntar si se encuentra vacia, y demas funciones.

**No es muy recomendable crear un arreglo para simular una pila!**

¿Que pasa si quiero agregar mas de 5 elementos?

A lo que quiero llegar es que haciendo una lista para simular la pila, el codigo queda mas sencillo.

Te puedo dar un ejemplo en c++:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

list<int> pila;

void agregar(int dato) {
    pila.push_front(dato);
}

int consultar_tope() {
    return pila.front();
}

void retirar() {
    pila.pop_front();
}

void imprimir_pila() {
    for (auto &i : pila)
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer con la pila?

¿Las operaciones básicas?

¿Sabes usar memoria en C?

Hace un rato hice un problema de pilas, con structs, son muy simples es parecido a tener una clase, solo que no quiero entrar a mayores detalles, en si te dejo un programa que hice hace tiempo, analizalo para que puedas entenderlo.
saludos.

```
/*
Proyecto Listas Pilas 
Estructura de Datos
Version: 1.2.41
*/
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
void atender();
void consulta();
void modificar();
void sacar();
void menu();
int gotoxy(int x, int y)//funcion paara posicionar texto en la pantalla 
{
    HANDLE hcon;
    hcon=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X=x;
    dwPos.Y=y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);

}
int n,m=100,i,cont=0;
struct Datos
{
    string nombre;
    int control;
};
Datos lista[100];
int aux=13,cons=14;
int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
void menu()//funcion menu creada
{
    int opc;
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(43,8);cout<<"+Menu+";
    gotoxy(43,10);cout<<"1.- Atender";
    gotoxy(43,11);cout<<"2.- Consultas";
    gotoxy(43,12);cout<<"3.- Modificar";
    gotoxy(43,13);cout<<"4.- Sacar";
    gotoxy(43,14);cout<<"5.- Salir";
    gotoxy(40,16);cout<<"Opcion:";
    cin>>opc;
    switch(opc) //casos del menu
    {
        case 1:
        atender();
        break;
        case 2:
        consulta();
        break;
        case 3:
        modificar();
        break;
        case 4:
        sacar();
        break;
        case 5:
        system("exit");
        break;
        default:
            system("cls");
            gotoxy(25,12);cout<<"Esa Opcion no Existe.\n";
            system("pause");
            menu();
    }
}
void atender()//Entrada a la cola 
{
    string exp;
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(33,12);cout<<"Ingresa el numero de datos que quieres almacenar:";
    cin>>n;
    if(n>m)
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(35,13);cout<<"Superas el Tamaño de Datos que se pueden Almacenar.\n";
        system("pause");
        atender();
    }
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(30,10);cout<"Ingresa tus Datos.";
    gotoxy(41,12);cout<<"---------------";gotoxy(57,12);cout<<"Control";
    for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
    {
        gotoxy(41,aux);cout<<"| ";gotoxy(56,aux);cout<<"|";
        gotoxy(41,cons);cout<<"---------------";
        aux+=2;
        cons+=2;
    }
    int z=13;
        for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
    {
        cont++;
        gotoxy(30,8);cout<<"La I: "<<cont<<" N: "<<n<<" M: "<<m;
        gotoxy(42,z);cin>>lista[a].nombre;gotoxy(58,z);cin>>lista[a].control;
        gotoxy(30,7);cout<<"Desea Ingresar otro dato (S/N):";
        cin>>exp;
        z+=2;
        if(exp=="N"||exp=="n")
        {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(35,14);cout<<"Se han Alamacenado correctamente los datos"<<endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        gotoxy(38,15);system("pause");
        system("cls");
        ofstream dat;
        dat.open("datos.txt",ios::out);
        if(dat.fail())
        {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(30,12);cout<<"El Archivo no existe";
        exit(1);
        }
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            dat<<lista[k].nombre<<" "<<lista[k].control<<endl;
        }
        dat.close();
        menu();
        }
    }
}
void consulta() //Consultas
{
    int llave;
    string r;
    aux=13;
    cons=14;
    if(n==0)
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(40,12);cout<<"La Lista esta Vacia";
        Sleep(1000);
        menu();
    }
    do
    {
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(38,2);cout<<"Consultas";
    gotoxy(30,9);cout<<"Ingresa el Control del Dato:";
    cin>>llave;
    int v=0;
    for(int h=0;h<n;h++)
    {

    if(llave==lista[h].control)
    {

        gotoxy(41,12);cout<<"---------------";
        gotoxy(41,aux);cout<<h+1<<"| "<<lista[h].nombre;gotoxy(56,aux);cout<<"|";
        gotoxy(41,cons);cout<<"---------------";
        gotoxy(35,10);cout<<"¡Dato encontrado!";
        gotoxy(30,8);cout<<"La I: "<<h+1<<" N: "<<n<<" M: "<<m;
        v++;
    }
    }
    if(v==0)
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(30,12);cout<<"El dato que buscas no existe"<<endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    gotoxy(35,16);cout<<"Desea otro proceso (S/N):";
    cin>>r;
    }
    while(r=="S"|| r=="s");
    menu();
}
void modificar()// Modificaciones
{   string pro;
    int llave;
    do{
    aux=13;
    cons=14;
    if(n==0)
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(40,12);cout<<"La Lista esta Vacia";
        Sleep(1000);
        menu();
    }
    system("cls");
    for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
    {
        gotoxy(41,12);cout<<"---------------";
        gotoxy(41,aux);cout<<b+1<<"| "<<lista[b].nombre;gotoxy(56,aux);cout<<"|";gotoxy(58,aux);cout<<lista[b].control;
        gotoxy(41,cons);cout<<"---------------";
        aux+=2;
        cons+=2;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    int v=0;
    gotoxy(32,10);cout<<"ingresa el control del dato que quieres modificar: ";
    cin>>llave;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
    if(llave==lista[j].control)
    {
    gotoxy(30,9);cout<<"La I: "<<j+1<<" N: "<<n<<" M: "<<m;
    gotoxy(32,11);cout<<"Ingresa el dato:";
    cin>>lista[j].nombre;
    v++;
    }
    }
    if(v==0)
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(30,12);cout<<"El dato que buscas no existe"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        modificar();
    }
    system("cls");
    aux=13;
    cons=14;
    for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
    {
        gotoxy(41,12);cout<<"---------------"<<" Control";
        gotoxy(41,aux);cout<<b+1<<"| "<<lista[b].nombre;gotoxy(56,aux);cout<<"|";gotoxy(58,aux);cout<<lista[b].control;
        gotoxy(41,cons);cout<<"---------------";
        aux+=2;
        cons+=2;
    }
    ofstream dato;
    dato.open("datos.txt",ios::out);
    dato.clear();
    if(dato.fail())
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(30,12);cout<<"El Archivo no existe";
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        dato<<lista[k].nombre<<endl;
    }
    dato.close();
    gotoxy(41,cons+1);cout<<"Dato Modificado con exito";
    gotoxy(41,cons+2);cout<<"Desea otro proceso (S/N): ";
    cin>>pro;
    }
    while(pro=="S"|| pro=="s");
    menu();
}
void sacar()//eliminando datos
{
    string esp;
    int llave;
    aux=13;
    cons=14;
    if(n==0)//Comparando
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(40,12);cout<<"La Lista esta Vacia";
        Sleep(1000);
        menu();
    }
    system("cls");
    int axv;
    axv=cont-1;
    for(int b=0;b<=cont-1;b++)
    {
        gotoxy(41,12);cout<<"---------------"<<" Control";
        gotoxy(41,aux);cout<<axv+1-b<<"| "<<lista[axv-b].nombre;gotoxy(56,aux);cout<<"|";gotoxy(58,aux);cout<<lista[axv-b].control;
        gotoxy(41,cons);cout<<"---------------";
        aux+=2;
        cons+=2;
    }
    Sleep(1500);
    int ax=0,v=0;//Atendiendo Datos Pilas
    gotoxy(30,cons);cout<<"Solo se puede sacar el ultimo dato que entro.";
    gotoxy(35,cons+1);cout<<"Desea Atender el ultimo dato (S/N):";
    cin>>esp;
    gotoxy(35,cons+2);cout<<"Se Entrego su Despensa"<<endl;
    gotoxy(30,9);cout<<"La I: "<<cont<<" N: "<<n<<" M: "<<m<<endl;
    system("pause");
    if(esp == "S"|| esp =="s")
    {
    int aux0;
    aux0=cont-1;
    for(int h=aux0;h<=n;h++)
    {
        lista[h]=lista[h+1];
    }
    n--;
    m--;
    cont--;
    system("cls");
    aux=13;
    cons=14;
    for(int b=0;b<n;b++)//imprimiendo lista de nuevo
    {
        gotoxy(41,12);cout<<"---------------";
        gotoxy(41,aux);cout<<b+1<<"| "<<lista[b].nombre;gotoxy(56,aux);cout<<"|";
        gotoxy(41,cons);cout<<"---------------";
        aux+=2;
        cons+=2;
    }
    gotoxy(35,10);cout<<"Dato atendido con exito"<<endl;
    ofstream dato;
    dato.open("datos.txt",ios::out);
    dato.clear();
    if(dato.fail())
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(30,12);cout<<"El Archivo no existe";
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        dato<<lista[k].nombre<<endl;
    }
    dato.close();
    gotoxy(30,20);cout<<"La I: "<<n<<" N: "<<n<<" M: "<<m<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
menu();
}//FIN
```